# custom modal won't close/cant close. Trying to open it on pageload with the ability to close. But it won't close

Tags: jquery

So I have a modal, that I got off a site, and I wanted to display it on page load, which it loads, but then I have the problem of not being able to close it.

http://jsfiddle.net/XjhQv/1/

I have for my jquery

```
function modalload(){
    jQuery('#contact').fadeIn("slow");
}

modalload();
```

But when I click the close button, it won't close. If you remove that jquery from the jsfiddle, you can open/close the button perfectly via the link. How would I make it so I would be able to close it too? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no eventlistener on your close button that tells your modal to close. Try adding this to your script:

```
$("a[href='#close']").click(function(){
   $('#contact').fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Note: you might wanna add a class or id to that close button

Comment: Works like a charm, Thanks! I also forgot to add an id to that close botton! Thanks again.